# How to manually hash blocks and transactions to get a better feel for the Ethereum protocol?

Tags: hash, keccak

Is there a way to easily get a transaction, the full transaction payload, and then hash it with keccak256 using a hash tool, to get a better feel for how the protocol works?

Ditto for full blocks.

I want to just manually do it one time with web3 or ethers to get a feel for it, somehow turn it into a binary or json and something and use a tool like: https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html